# Errors not written to Apache error log

Tags: php, apache, error-logging

I've had a problem with some Apache web server error logs.

I have a virtually hosted website scotthermmann.loc on my computer. After I manually clear an error log, using

```
sudo cat /dev/null > scotthermmann.loc-error_log
```

or by opening the file in emacs & deleting all content, errors no longer get logged to the file. I've tried using

```
sudo apachectl restart
```

to solve the problem, but it doesn't solve it. Logging out & back in doesn't solve it either. What does solve it is restarting the computer, but I don't want to do that after every time I clear an error log.

This isn't the case for every website I host. I have another website barefootfool.loc. After I clear that error log, I don't have any problems.

Both virtual sites have essentially the same setup in the httpd-vhosts.conf file. For scottherrmann.loc:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Users/dan/Sites/scottherrmann.com"
    ServerName scottherrmann.loc
    ServerAlias www.scottherrmann.loc
    ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/scottherrmann.loc-error_log"
    CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/scottherrmann.loc-access_log"

    <Directory "/Users/dan/Sites/scottherrmann.com">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from all 
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And for barefootfool.loc:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Users/dan/Sites/barefootfool.com"
    ServerName barefootfool.loc
    ServerAlias www.barefootfool.loc
    ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/barefootfool.loc-error_log"
    CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/barefootfool.loc-access_log"

    <Directory "/Users/dan/Sites/barefootfool.com">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from all 
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Does anyone have an idea what could be causing the problem?

Comment: Check the permissions of the error log file. Make sure that the apache user can write to them.

Answer (score 8):

I just had this it was because I inadvisably deleted the /var/log/httpd/error_log file and then touched a new log file.

```
service httpd restart
```

cleared the problem . next time I'll truncate the error_log with

```
:>error_log
```

Comment: Got, it - it's a null statement (http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Builtins.html#index-_003a). Why would `cat /dev/null > log` not work as opposed to the null statement?..

Comment: It would be `service apache2 restart` for Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

Probably it is because you run the tomcat with the user `apachectl` and when you clear the log file with the command `sudo cat /dev/null > scotthermmann.loc-error_log` the user that execute this command take the ownership of the file then the user `apachectl` can't write on it anymore. Try to run the cleanup command as this:

```
sudo apachectl cat /dev/null > scotthermmann.loc-error_log
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. The permissions appear to be correct. The permissions for all log files are -rw-r--r--, for owner root:wheel. I've checked after I run the cat command, & after I clear the log with emacs, & the permissions & owner remain the same. When I restart the computer, the permissions don't change, but I am able to write to the log file again. I'm not familiar with Tomcat (I don't use Java). Apachectl is not a user. I'm using the "apachectl" command because I thought maybe restarting the apache server would solve the problem of not being able to write to logs.